# how to vertically top align a slide in beamer?

Tags: beamer, align

The following beamer slide (and all other slides) have the text vertically centered. How do I get it to appear at the top of the slide?

```
      \documentclass[sansserif,mathserif]{beamer}

      \begin{document}

      \begin{frame}{centered frame}
      centered text, how to get it to top?
      \end{frame}

      \end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get this option globally

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    Text on top
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
\begin{frame}[t]

Frame contents

\end{frame}
```

does the job

Comment: Any option to do that globally?